# returning part of regex string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the video id of a youtube video using regex.

I have the following regex:

```
var VideoID = inputstring.match(/watch\?v=[A-Z,a-z,0-9]+($|\&)/);
```

This works fine. If i for instance put in:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prHVlkFM9oc&index=9&list=RDxEwgEw3k6UA
```

It return this:

```
watch?v=prHVlkFM9oc&
```

But I only want the [A-Z,a-z,0-9]+ part of the regex (prHVlkFM9oc in the above code).

How do I get this? I could cut away 9 chars from the start after the regex returns, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Commas in a character class have no special meaning and are not used to separate ranges, so you can remove them. `&` is not a special character in a pattern, there is no need to escape it.

Comment: regular expressions are the wrong tool for parsing a query string.

Comment: What is the right tool then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use parenthesis `( )` to catch the part that you want to grab:

```
var match = inputstring.match(/watch\?v=([A-Za-z0-9]+)($|&)/);

// returns ["watch?v=prHVlkFM9oc&", "prHVlkFM9oc", "&"]
```

Now your result is in `match[1]`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use a captured group here and grab the first index of the resulting array:

```
var VideoID = ( inputstring.match(/watch\?v=([^&]+)/) || ['', ''])[1];
//=> prHVlkFM9oc
```

Comment: I presume case [' ', ' '] fires if the first regex returns no matches?

Comment: yes that is for safeguard measure if `matches` fail.

Comment: Good idea, deserves an upvote, however why not simply use `[]` instead of `['','']`, the match would be undefined which makes total sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are ok with VideoId variable you can do folowing:
var parts = VideoId.split("="); so you can get that part as parts[1]